# right way to use the SFC options /offbootdir and /offwindir. Why they do not work as expected

Tags: windows-8, system-restore

Several times i try to repair w8pro using `sfc /scannow` in various manners in elevated cmd or from usb recovery console with different additional options, i always get stuck with unable to repair because no source files. It seems that `/offbootdir=<path to my unpaked install.wim>` does not work for sfc. Where do i place files that **sfc** could find them? I think about dll cache but i do not know how to  it in **w8**

Comment: in fact it was too general, ok changed

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 8 use the new [DISM command to fix file corruptions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx)

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

When Windows detects corrupted files it will download them. You can also use the command offline and [point to a WIM](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2013/03/29/features-on-demand-part-2.aspx) to get the data:

```
Dism /image:C:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:D:\install.wim:2
```

Comment: super! I feel this will help me. a question before applying what does  ":2 " mean? do I need invoke dism from recovery or elevated prompt would be enough?

Comment: this is the Index. A WIM can contain more than 1 Windows edition.

Comment: @Yurij73 did it worked as expected or not?